# EMR 5.4.0 High Availability

Tags: amazon-emr

Does EMR 5.4.0 supports HA for Resource Manager, Namenode and Hive? if not any road map for the same?

i am not able to get it from the EMR documentation site 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide

please suggest if you find any useful document

Answer (score 4):

As of Feb 2018 AWS  EMR has a single point of failure at Master Node.

[EMR FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/faqs/)
Look at :
Q: If the master node in a cluster goes down, can Amazon EMR recover it?

If HA is necessary requirement then you would want to consider either Cloud Offerings from Cloudera/Hortonworks/Mapr or Custom Installations on AWS EC2s.

Answer (score 2):

To help people coming to this post for EMR HA queries.
Finally, as of writing this on may 2019, HA is made GA on AWS EMR. More information in the AWS post below.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-emr-announces-support-for-multiple-master-nodes-to-enable-high-availability-for-EMR-applications/